# Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED react-native

Tags: react-native

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> com.gwtapp-mergeDebugResources-36:/values/values.xml:1016: error: resource drawable/rn_edit_text_material (aka com.gwtapp:drawable/rn_edit_text_material) not found.
> com.gwtapp-mergeDebugResources-36:/values/values.xml:1016: error: resource drawable/rn_edit_text_material (aka com.gwtapp:drawable/rn_edit_text_material) not found.
> error: failed linking references.

I have tried many methods to solve the problem but I can't solve it, can you help me somehow?